# How to remove blinking in leaflet with invalidateLater shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

It's an old problem which I think was never solved. Blinking in leaflet map when use `invalidateLater()`.

**Example**

[image: here].

**The app code:**

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(

            tags$style(type="text/css", ".recalculating { opacity: 1.0 !important; }"),

            leafletOutput("mymap")

      )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

      output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({

            invalidateLater(1000)
            leaflet(quakes[1:10,])%>% 
                  addTiles() %>%
                  addMarkers()
      })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Joe Cheng recommended [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/9faA5OUm2Hc)

`tags$style(type="text/css", ".recalculating { opacity: 1.0 !important; }")`

and it's works perfectly fine e.g. in `ggplot2` charts, but not in `leaflet` map.

Is there any workaround how to remove blinking in this app? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it should be `tags$style(type="text/css", " .leaflet-fade-anim .leaflet-tile, .leaflet-fade-anim .leaflet-popup {opacity: 1 !important;}")` instead of `tags$style(type="text/css", ".recalculating { opacity: 1.0 !important; }")`.

Comment: It doesn't work either.

Comment: Actually it works partially. It's better but still sometimes blinking occurs. Interestingly not every second, but sometime.

Comment: I guess the blinking would be for markers. Will have to look into the css of leaflet to find out.